# Mudar a função nativa do console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js

Existe alguma forma de mudar a função nativa do console.log, mas manter a antiga?

Ex:

```
console.log = (e) => {
     antigoConsoleLog(e);
     alert(e); //exemplo
     minhaFuncao(e); //exemplo
}
```

Comment: Você não explicou o propósito, mas fica uma recomendação: Reactotron

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Poder podes... mas desaconselho. Outras pessoas que estejam a usar o teu código vão ter sérios problemas em encontrar onde esse método foi sobre-escrito.

Tendo dito isso, podes por exemplo adicionar `>>>` a todos os logs assim:

```js
globalThis.console = {
  log: console.log.bind(null, '>>>>')
}
console.log('Teste!');
```

Podes manter uma referência à antiga também:

```js
globalThis.consolaAntiga = console;
globalThis.console = {
  log(...args) {
    globalThis.consolaAntiga.log(':::', ...args);
  }
}
console.log('Teste!');
globalThis.consolaAntiga.log('Teste 2');
```

Esse código funciona no Browser e no Node.js

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou perfeitamente aqui

Comment: só teve um problema, no node eu tive que usar uma função que eu encontrei no GitHub. [LINK DA PAGINA NO GITHUB](https://gist.github.com/shisama/52194cb11d9caf1177851db12c012849)

Comment: Estás a usar uma versão antiga do Node? @LuísHNrique o que dá `node -v` no terminal?